# Safely recompiling all assets on Rails 4 deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Right now I have occasional issues with the Rails 4 asset pipeline that requires removing all assets and then recreating the assets.

During deployment, after pulling the latest from git, I refresh the assets by running, `rake assets:clobber` and then `rake assets:precompile` on my server. The problem is that during the time the assets are removed, the page gets served, not surprisingly, with no assets.

Is there anyway to force Rails to recompile all assets without having to run `assets:clobber`?

Comment: What are the occasional issues? That is what you should be fixing. Can you elaborate on that problem, maybe come up with the steps to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I usually do, when precompiling the assets.

```
// At a terminal, remove all assets from the file system
$ rm -rf public/assets  
// Precompile the assets
$ rake assets:precompile
```

Always worked for me.

Comment: That's essentially what clobber does. The problem is that incoming requests are served with no assets when that directory is deleted.

Comment: The second command would compile the assets from scratch... but, it doesn't do that on your box, huh?

Comment: `precompile` works, the problem is that there is a window where there is nothing in `/public/assets`

Comment: Is this happening in your production environment? If so, where are you hosting you app? If this happens in your development envirnoment, you should not precompile assets but serve them dynamically so you can test your changes. I just don't understand why you have to recompile assets when they are already deployed. You should precompile them as part of deployment.

Comment: It is in prod. It's just need picking up all changes unfortunately.

Comment: So, what you are saying is, when you deploy to prod after doing a recompilation, the changes are not picked up? There is something wrong with your setting. Where are you hosting your app in? Also, have you checked all the config files (especially the production.rb)?

Comment: I am doing the recompilation of the assets in production.

Answer (score 0):

First run `rake assets:precompile` then run `rake assets:clean`. That will only remove old assets. https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/README.md#rake-task

Comment: So in Rails 4 `precompile` attempts to only compile new files, but I've had some issues with not working 100% (especially for the Less gem). So the problem with this solution is that it wouldn't recompile files that it considered not changed.

Comment: one solution would be to host it via a CDN which will cache the assets during your clobber time

Comment: Jeff Dickey talks sense.